# Merge equal objects using high order functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, lodash

I'd like to "merge" objects from an array if they have values equal to each other.

Here's an example:

```
"relations_entities": [
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": string,
      "inEntityId": string,
      "outEntityId": string,
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": string,
          "confidence": number,
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": string,
      "label": string,
      "text": string,
    },
  },
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": string,
      "inEntityId": string,
      "outEntityId": string,
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": string,
          "confidence": number,
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": string,
      "label": string,
      "text": string,
    },
  },
]
```

and if `relations_entities[0].relation.label` and `relations_entities[0].entity.label` are equal to `relations_entities[0].relation.label` and `relations_entities[0].entity.label`

Then I need this object to be:

```
"relations_entities": [
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": string,
      "inEntityId": string,
      "outEntityId": string,
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": string,
          "confidence": number,
        },
        {
          "text": string,
          "confidence": number,
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": string,
      "label": string,
      "text": string,
    },
  },
]
```

The two proofs merged.

I tried implementing this behavior using filters but I lost my mind.

Maybe using lodash library?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is es6 syntax ok? Will the structure always be the same with the same value types

Comment: @MatthewBrent I use TypeScript, so, yeah!

Comment: is label the only key that needs to be checked in order to merge the objects?

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro for the moment, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on it:

```js
let relations_entities = [
  {
    relation: {
      label: 'string',
      inEntityId: 'string',
      outEntityId: 'string',
      proof: [
        {
          text: 'string',
          confidence: 'number',
        }
      ],
    },
    entity: {
      entityId: 'string',
      label: 'string',
      text: 'string',
    },
  },
  {
    relation: {
      label: 'string',
      inEntityId: 'string',
      outEntityId: 'string',
      proof: [
        {
          text: 'string',
          confidence: 'number',
        }
      ],
    },
    entity: {
      entityId: 'string',
      label: 'string',
      text: 'string',
    },
  },
];

let merged = [];

relations_entities.forEach(el => {
  let found = false;  
  if (merged.length > 0) {
    merged.forEach(elM => {
      if (el.relation.label === elM.relation.label && !found) {
        elM.relation.proof = elM.relation.proof.concat(el.relation.proof);
        found = true;
      }
    });
  } 
  if (!found || merged.length === 0) {
    merged.push(el);
  }
});

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using es6 fat arrow functions, this could be improved by passing in the keys you wish to check by. If you require this functionality I don't mind adding this in to your answer for completeness.

```js
var relations_entities = [
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": 'a',
      "inEntityId": '123',
      "outEntityId": '123',
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": '123',
          "confidence": '123',
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": '123',
      "label": '123',
      "text": '123',
    },
  },
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": 'b',
      "inEntityId": '321',
      "outEntityId": '321',
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": '321',
          "confidence": '321',
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": '321',
      "label": '123',
      "text": '321',
    },
  },
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": 'c',
      "inEntityId": '321',
      "outEntityId": '321',
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": '321',
          "confidence": '321',
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": '321',
      "label": '123',
      "text": '321',
    },
  },
  {
    "relation": {
      "label": 'b',
      "inEntityId": '321',
      "outEntityId": '321',
      "proof": [
        {
          "text": '321',
          "confidence": '321',
        }
      ],
    },
    "entity": {
      "entityId": '321',
      "label": '123',
      "text": '321',
    },
  }
]

const compareEntities = (oldEntities) => {
  // early breakout if there is just one element
  if (oldEntities.length === 0) {
    return oldEntities
  }
  
  // here we iterate through each of the passed in entities
  var newEntities = oldEntities.filter((entity, index, entities) => {
    // set the internal counter to 1 higher than the filtered counter
    // (the next object along)
    var i = index + 1
    const relationlabel = entity.relation.label
    const entityLabel = entity.entity.label

    // iterate through each remaining entity and remove from array if there is a match
    while (i < entities.length) {
      const relationLabelIsEqual = relationlabel === entities[i].relation.label
      const entityLabelIsEqual = relationlabel === entities[i].relation.label
      if (relationLabelIsEqual && entityLabelIsEqual) {
        i = index + 1
        return false
      }
      // if there is no match we just want to move onto the next entity
      ++i
    }
    // if we have iterated through all entities then there was no match
    // - return it into the new array
    return true
  })
  return newEntities
}

console.log(compareEntities(relations_entities))
```

You can also play with a [repl i set up](https://repl.it/@mattjbrent/filterOnValue)